# Postgresql 10 PL/pgSQL function array parameter

Tags: php, postgresql, plpgsql

I´m solving problem with PL/pgSQL function and I still can´t find clear aswer.

I need to call my function in PHP (7.2) and send an array like this one. It is array of arrays.

```
[
    [value1(numeric), value2(timestamp)],
    [value1(numeric), value2(timestamp)]
];
```

And then I need to loop over this array and access every value.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

In general I know that PHP (PDO) still is not well prepared for these situations.

Thank you very much for your answers and advices

Comment: Do you need to loop the array inside the plpgsql function?

Comment: Hello, yes I do. Now I´m thinking that I will not send an array but a JSON. Isnt that more effective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A array value can be created as literal or as functions or array constructor result. You have to know:

- PostgreSQL arrays are multidimensional.
- PostgreSQL supports array of composite types
- Arrays of arrays are not supported.
- PostgreSQL's arrays are homogeneous - can holds a values of only one type.

So for your purpose probably you should to create own custom type, maybe constructor for this custom type.

```
CREATE mytype AS(value1 numeric, value2 timestamp);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mytype_new(numeric, timestamp)
RETURNS mytype AS $$
SELECT ROW($1, $2)::mytype;
$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc(a mytype[])
RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE i mytype;
BEGIN
  FOREACH i IN ARRAY a
  LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE '%', i;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

you can create a array with type constructors:

```
postgres=# select myfunc(array[mytype_new(1, current_timestamp::timestamp), mytype_new(2, current_timestamp::timestamp)]);
NOTICE:  (1,"2018-11-04 05:32:55.579313")
NOTICE:  (2,"2018-11-04 05:32:55.579313")
```

or you can enter value as literal (attention, the values should be correctly quoted and escaped):

```
postgres=# select myfunc('{"(1,2018-11-04 05:32:28.44918)","(2,2018-11-04 05:32:28.44918)"}');
NOTICE:  (1,"2018-11-04 05:32:28.44918")
NOTICE:  (2,"2018-11-04 05:32:28.44918")
```

These last two selects can you can run from PHP.

Comment: Hello Pavel, sorry for my late answer. I understand your solution in general. But what about performance? Is this acceptable? This is my situation I´m solving:

Comment: Hello Pavel, sorry for my late answer. I understand your solution in general. But what about performance? Is this acceptable? This is my situation I´m solving:

On 99% there will be only this: [value1, value2].
But it can also happen the situation in my first question. And that array can have length of 1000. So I´m looking also for good performance. And I´m not sure about your solution, because there is a lot of casting. And I know that you are a professional (postgres.cz).

Now i realized that I can send a JSON to that function and loop over it. Isnt that easier and more effective?

Comment: @Vole - It depends what you are do inside function and where and what is the bottleneck. Usually this should not be performance problem - common bottlenecks are elsewhere. The performance arrays of composites should be better than json, but for small sizes (1000 is small) the difference will not be visible probably. If performance is important for you, test both. JSON is saved as string, and it can be parsed every time. Hard to say what factor is significant for your specific case.